# Can't Create a Welcome Screen Which but the formatting of the layout isn't currently working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Currently I am trying to make a layout that looks like this:

[image: Example of Welcome Page Layout Picture]

The left side will redirect a user to a unique create account page depending on which button they clicked to say what sort of user they are (each type of user requires different data). And then, on the right side I want the button to redirect the user to a sign in page.

The boxes are where I want each widget should be located.

Any suggestions/ examples on how to do this or corrections to the following code will be amazing!!!

My (very) broken code is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import sys
import os
os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"

stylesheet = """
    QWidget{
        background-color: white;
    }

    QLabel#titleOfPage{
        font: 25px;
    }

    QLabel#genText{
        font: 15px;
    }
"""
#note that the last 3 are useless currently



class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Public Transport Application")
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 500)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Icon.jpg'))
        self.showMaximized()

        self.welcomePage()


    def welcomePage (self):

        #this is me trying to get a title at the top of the page (doesn't work)
        titleWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        title = QtWidgets.QLabel('Welcome to the Queensland Transport Application')
        title.setObjectName('titleOfPage')

        titleWidget.setFixedHeight(100)



        #This is then me trying to create all the layoute for both sides so I can start adding things to either side (note ca means create account and si means sign in)
        layoutL = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layoutL.addWidget(titleWidget)

        layoutL.addWidget(title)

        layoutCaSi = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.screenLayout = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()

        layoutL.addLayout(self.screenLayout)

        caWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        caLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        caLayout.addWidget(caWidget)

        siWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        siLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        siLayout.addWidget(siWidget)


        layoutCaSi.addLayout(caLayout)
        layoutCaSi.addLayout(siLayout)

        layoutCaSi.addLayout(self.screenLayout)

        layoutL.addLayout(layoutCaSi)

    #this will be my create account page
    def caPage(self):
        pass

    #this will be my sign in page
    def siPage(self):
        pass

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `QGridLayout` on the central widget of your main window. I've used two QSpacerItems to keep the widgets centered between the title label and the bottom. Btw, the style sheet `QWidget {background-color: white;}` will apply to everything that inherits from QWidget, including all the buttons and labels, not sure if you want that.

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Public Transport Application")
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 500)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Icon.jpg'))
        self.showMaximized()
        self.welcomePage()

    def welcomePage(self):
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        grid.setVerticalSpacing(40) # Vertical space between widgets

        title = QtWidgets.QLabel('Welcome to the Queensland Transport Application')
        title.setObjectName('titleOfPage')
        title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        title.setFixedHeight(100)

        grid.addWidget(title, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addItem(QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding), 1, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel('Text'), 2, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter)
        grid.addWidget(QPushButton('Button 1'), 3, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter)
        grid.addWidget(QPushButton('Button 2'), 4, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter)
        grid.addWidget(QPushButton('Button 3'), 5, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter)
        grid.addWidget(QPushButton('Button'), 2, 1, 4, 1, Qt.AlignHCenter)
        grid.addItem(QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding), 6, 0, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And yeah I fixed the QWidget thing (I forgot to specify what it was for). Although one question I have is, how do I have each of the button then redirect to another function? And also thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Josh Construct the button and then connect one of its signals to your function. E.g. `btn = QPushButton('Button 1')` `btn.clicked.connect(self.do_something)` `grid.addWidget(btn, 3, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter)`